# Converting string to int problems in C++

Tags: c++, atoi

Sorry for any mistakes, first time questioning here.
so i have this function where i have a vector  type with names and scores of players of a game, while im trying to make a ranking wall.
in this specific part of the program i need to convert a string to a int. the string part is actually a number in the string vector and i need it to be int so i can compare it with other numbers, so here it is:

```
void exibir_ranking(vector<string> &ranking) //dentro do laco, procura qual o maior score, imprime ele na tela juntamente com o nome correspondente no outro vetor depois apaga o valor e o nome dos vectors
{
    int k;
    vector <string> nomes;
    vector <int> pontuacoes;

    for(int i=0;i<ranking.max_size();i++) {
        if(i==0 || i%2 ==0) nomes.push_back(ranking[i]);
        else if(i==1 || i%2!=0) {
            int aux = atoi(ranking[i].c_str);
            pontuacoes.push_back(aux);          
        }
    }


    cout << "\n\n\t\tRANKING:\n\n";
    while(pontuacoes.size()!=0){
        int maior =0;
        for (k=0; k< pontuacoes.max_size(); k++){
            if(pontuacoes[k] > maior) maior = pontuacoes[k];
        }
        cout << k << "- " << "Nome: " << nomes[k] << "\tScore: "<<pontuacoes[k] << endl;
        nomes.erase (nomes.begin()+k);
        pontuacoes.erase (pontuacoes.begin()+k);
    }
    cout<<"\n----------------------------";

}
```

---

so, visual studio is telling me the problem is exactly here:

```
else if(i==1 || i%2!=0) {
    int aux = atoi(ranking[i].c_str);
    pontuacoes.push_back(aux);          
}
```

as is says:

> Error 4 error C3867: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::c_str': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::c_str' to create a pointer to member   c:\users\user\google drive\mackenzie\projeto programacao\projeto\projeto\jogo.cpp   247

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why are you using `max_size()`? Just use `size()`.

Comment: `int aux = atoi(ranking[i].c_str);` - I suppose you meant to **call** that member function? like `c_str()`?

Answer (score 5):

Use `()` to call a function, `c_str` is a function not a variable:

```
ranking[i].c_str()
                ^^
```

In addition, having C++, you can use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to stop using `c_str`, it also throws exception if the entry is not valid to convert to an integer:

```
int aux = stoi(ranking[i]);
```

And, replace `max_size()` by `size()` to get the real size of the vector, not the maximum possible size.

Answer (score 1):

`c_str()` is a function, so you must call it:

```
aux = atoi(ranking[i].c_str());
//                         ^^
```

And like I said in the commments, I also see that you're using `max_size()`. This is probably causing a lot of problems in your program as this method returns the maximum size a vector can hold, not the amount of elements current residing in it. When you access the element at the index greater than the size of the container, and dereference it, you will get Undefined Behavior for accessing an out of bounds address.

The correct method to use is `size()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ranking.size(); ++i)
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```